# PhpDoc adding notation for self in a file included inside a class

Tags: php, phpdoc

I have a class which includes a file in a method like below:

In `class.php` file:

```
class A {

const CONST1 = 5;

/** @var int $a */
var $a = 5;

public function call()
{
    include( 'b.php' );
}

public function do_some_magic()
{
    // magic stuff...
}

public static function static_func()
{
    // some code...
}

}
```

file `b.php`:

```
<?php
/** @var A $this */
/** @var A self */ // This doesn't work

$this->do_some_magic();

echo '['.$this->a.']';

self::static_func();

echo '['.self::CONST1.']';
```

I use PhpStorm as IDE and in `b.php` file if I want to go to definition of `do_some_magic()` or definition of `a` variable it will correctly go to corresponding method or variable definition in `class.php` file, but if I want to go to definition of constant CONST1 or to definition of static method `static_func()` it says "Cannot find definition to go to", so I think `/** @var A self */` is not a valid notation in included file.

My question is: Is there any way in PhpDoc to tell IDE of what type `self` is in included file?

Comment: Why do you use `include()` within a class method?

Comment: I use this in particular case of a WordPress plugin to include a view which should display a form or a specific functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched for an answer, but as it seems at the moment only way to have auto-complete in an included file you will have to make static calls using class name. Of course, this would fail if you include the file in different classes and you want self to mean that specific class where the file was included.

So `b.php` would look like:

```
<?php
/** @var A $this */
/** @var A self */ // This doesn't work

$this->do_some_magic();

echo '['.$this->a.']';

A::static_func();

echo '['.A::CONST1.']';
```

If however you find a better answer please let me know.

Regards,

Andy

Comment: In PHPstorm, when something like this appears I use your notation `@var ClassName $this` and references work well, so I suppose this could be the real answer :-)

Comment: @ErenorPaz unfortunately, that seems only to reveal public methods and members. It's better than nothing, though.

Comment: @ErenorPaz Actually, although it doesn't suggest protected/private members, it still knows what they are. This is actually very useful. Supposing `$this` is class `foo`, which has a protected member object of class `baz`. Inside my included file of class `foo`, I can set `$baz = $this->baz;` (PhpStorm will not suggest $baz because it's protected). Then, if I start typing `$baz->`, PhpStorm will suggest all public methods and members of `baz`. Still, not being able to get autocompletion for non-public `foo` components is a problem.